# Google Maps - Custom Background Image

Tags: php, google-maps

I've been asked to create a custom map for a client, similar to [this one here](http://brickellhouse.com/location.php). I've taken a look at the JS, and I really like how it was done but I can't seem to find anwhere they would've defined the custom background image. Furthermore, I can't find clear documentation on something like this.

To be clear, my client would like all of the same functionality but the background would of course be different.

Could someone point me in the direction of how this would be done with Google Maps' API or even how they did it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it recently, or something not quite as ambitious as the link, following the docs.  It's not a background image, but you can literally change the road type, etc with css/javascript https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.  If you need to limit the zoom degrees of freedom, like in the map, then change the map controls, as they did.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.  All the magic happens on the website you linked to at: http://brickellhouse.com/js/location.min.js  and http://brickellhouse.com/css/map.css

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To add to IntheNoob's post, the actual background of that google maps is merely a large image overlay. They then added listeners for the menu actions & some minor styles on the roads and such. If you look at this image from brickellhouse.com you'll see what I mean:

http://brickellhouse.com/images/gmaps/map.jpg

[a brickellhouse map bg http://brickellhouse.com/images/gmaps/map.jpg](http://brickellhouse.com/images/gmaps/map.jpg)